# How can I grant permissions to my mounted disk?

Tags: permissions, mount, hard-drive

I reinstalled my OS, but now a data-disk gives permission errors. I did `umount` then `sudo mount /dev/sdb1  /data`, but still  this disk is still only accessible through `sudo`.

Even after `chmod a+rw /data`, resulting in permission-bits `drwxrw-rw-`, this directory and all the files inside it are inaccessible (except with `sudo`).

```
$ ls data
ls: cannot access 'data/Music': Permission denied
ls: cannot access 'data/Templates': Permission denied
...  Music     Templates
```

How to I give myself permissions to this directory and its subdirectories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you could change the permissions of **all** the directories under `data` with the `-R` flag (your command `chmod a+rw /data` just modified the permissions of the `/data` directory, not its **contents**):

```
chmod -R a+rw /data
```

this is *almost never* a good idea (i.e. to give **everybody** access to everything!).

A more appropriate approach would be to change the **ownership** of the files and directories to you:

```
chown -R yourusername:yourgroup /data
```

Well, unless your `/dev/sdb1` is a removable (USB?) disk. In that case it might get complicated (and outside the scope of this answer) so probably the `chmod -R` is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you. The chown does the trick. But which  group should I use?  The command groups joshua gives "joshua : joshua adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare". i will be defining this internal harddrive as my main user disk, for example, setting Desktop /Documents/Videos to point into /data

Comment: Your group is the same as your username. If your username is `joshua` your group is also `joshua` by default. As you found out, you also belong to some other groups, such as adm, cdrom, sudo, etc.